# express server getting AWS AccessDeniedException, but AWS CLI works

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cli

I am running an express node server that makes calls to AWS Dynamodb/KMS
I have setup my ~/.aws/config and ~/.aws/credentials and i am pretty sure the express is picking up these configs.

Now the problem is that when i run the express server i get AccessDeniedException exception(AccessDeniedException: User: arn:xxx is not authorized to perform) for my user. However when i use AWS cli i am able to access the dynamodb/KMS without any problems.

i might be wrong but it looks to me like both cli and express are using the same account to access AWS. How is it possible that one is failing? Also is there any way to verify that my express and cli are using the same aws account?

Sample code that i use to access dynamo is this:

```
const DynamoDB = require("aws-sdk/clients/dynamodb");
const docClient = new DynamoDB.DocumentClient({region: "us-east-1"});
```

Comment: 1) Double check that the user ARN matches the user that you think you are using. 2) The simplest is to just declare your Access Key and Secret Key in your code when creating the client. You will know for sure which credentials you are using then.

Comment: I have a suggestion to run aws cli with --debug and inspect users by which you are calling the api. This will give you more insight of what you are calling using cli

Comment: You can try it with configuring it with profiles at both places CLI and express server. First set those credentials using profile and then try to access dynemo using CLI and code, but for code you need to maintain profile in code to let the program know which credentials to use

Answer (score 0):

`How is it possible that one is failing?`

`AccessDeniedException` For this you can try the following:

1. So AWS SDK fetches creds in a precedence. Check where your application is trying to get creds from. Best way is to define AWS Creds as Environment variables so that application can use them
2. If the user which is used does not have complete permission in policies attached.
3. Verify what action you are trying to perform using AWS CLI and AWS SDK. Try to perform the same actions with same creds.

**To answer your question that** `is there any way to verify that my express and cli are using the same aws account?`

4. Basically it should use the profile mentioned in your `.aws/config` file. But for confirmation you can use `profile` property in your code while you are calling your sdk like this:

```
const DynamoDB = require("aws-sdk/clients/dynamodb");
const docClient = new DynamoDB.DocumentClient({region: "us-east-1"},{profile: <name>});
```